# Split the data in a column excel

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a column that contains data for eg: 6B31-21045M22-AA
I'm trying to split the data before and after '-'. Like

```
A                  B     C         D
6B31-21045M22-AA   6B31  21045M22  AA
```

I tried

```
 =LEFT(A2, SEARCH(“-”,A2)-1)  and =Right(A2, SEARCH(“-”,A2)-1)
```

but if "-" occurs more than once then how do i split the 6B31-21045M22-AA or
 6B31-21045M22-AA-SWQ

Comment: This is not a programming question

Answer (score 4):

You don't need a formula or a VBA script. You can use [Text to Columns function](http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/text-to-columns.html). Simply select the column with your data and use Text to Columns button on the Data panel. Then in a Wizard select Delimiter and set a "-" symbol as a delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

With data in **A1**, in **B1** enter:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE($A1,"-",REPT(" ",999)),COLUMNS($A:A)*999-998,999))
```

and copy across:

[image]

*(this can also be done with VBA)*

**EDIT#1:**

Using VBA, `select` the cell you wish to process and run this:

```
Sub Splitter()
    Dim ary, i As Long, a
    With ActiveCell
        ary = Split(.Value, "-")
        i = 1
        For Each a In ary
            .Offset(0, i).Value = a
            i = i + 1
        Next a
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: How do i do with VBA?

Comment: @sam  See **EDIT#1.**, to process more than a single cell, use a loop structure.